# Does glibc (GNU C Library) provide a way to obtain the size of an allocated memory block?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, x86-64, glibc

I have a pointer. I know its address (I got as an argument to a function), and I know that it points to a memory address previously allocated by the `malloc()` call.

Is there any way to know the size of this allocated memory block?

I would prefer a cross-platform, standard solution, but I think these do not exist. Thus, anything is okay, even hardcore low-level malloc data structure manipulation, if there is no better. I use glibc with x86_64 architecture and there is no plan to run the result elsewhere. *I am not looking for a generic answer, it can be specific to glibc/x86_64.*

I think, this information should be available, otherways `realloc()` could not work.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492384/1783163) asks for a generic, standard-compliant solution, which is impossible. I am looking for a glibc/x86_64 solution which is possible, because the glibc is open source and the glibc `realloc()` needs this to work, and this question allows answers by digging in non-standard ways in the low-levels malloc internals.

Comment: `x = malloc(HEREISTHESIZE);`

Comment: `malloc` does not have standard implementation, so this info *might* be available in non-portable ways on some known implementations.

Comment: @pmg As the title says, I only know the memory address (x), and I do not know `HEREISTHESIZE`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think it should be, otherways `realloc()` could not work.

Comment: `realloc` knows exactly how `malloc` is implemented and is using the same internal bookkeeping. Moreover it does not have to. It just needs to `malloc` with new size, copy data there and `free` the old pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. And, glibc being open source, also I can get some access to this internal bookkeeping. *"anything is okay, even hardcore low-level malloc data structure manipulation, if there is no better."*...

Comment: @EugeneSh. But `free()` needs to know the size.

Comment: Sure you can. But if tomorrow glibc is changing the implementation, you can throw your code to trash.

Comment: One possible scheme is that bookkeeping is allocated *before* the address in the pointer.  The library would know how to get to the bookkeeping details by subtracting from the pointer value.  There are more than one method to allocate memory.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, if you know only the address and not at least a lower bound on the size, then there are only a few things you can safely do with the addess, chiefly: store it in a variable or pass it to another function.  Particular cases of the latter of special interest include `free`ing the pointer and `realloc`ing it.  You cannot dereference it, and there is no standard function to determine the size of the allocated block.

Comment: Why do you need this so badly that you're willing to use implementation-specific methods? Everyone else handles it by passing the size as an additional parameter or using a `struct` to hold the size and pointer.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily. There are some "poor man" implementations without bookeeping at all. Such as https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html#heap_1

Comment: Also, the `malloc` and the `new` functions are allowed to allocate more space than requested.  One reason would be for alignment purposes.  Another could be that the memory allocation allocates the entire remaining memory and only trims as needed.  So many more possibilities.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the content of a pointer points to *heap* memory or a dynamically allocated object.  Addresses of variables and constants can be passed to functions.

Comment: There is no portable way; the standard simply doesn't mandate one.  For glibc, look up `malloc_usable_size()` but be aware that it is mainly intended for debugging.  Note that it can be greater than the size originally passed to `malloc`; most implementations don't record that size anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar Because I am developing a glibc malloc hook. This hooked version will use the glibc malloc for small allocations, and my own implementation for large ones. Now the problem appears if I want to develop the hooked version of my `realloc`. Yes, I know, there are other ways to avoid this, this question looks now for the option if I really dig into the malloc internals. Thus, this question is not a dupe.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As the question explains, this is for the glibc malloc, which is not a poor mans implementation, and allows answers based on implementation-specific data structures.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As the question explains, *"I know that it points to a memory address previously allocated by the malloc() call."*, thus undefined behavior is acceptable if it is not a previously malloc()-ed pointer.

Comment: A classic example is a pointer to an array.  Most pointers point to the first element.  There is no guarantee that there are consecutive slots or the quantity; that information cannot be gleamed from the pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge No problem if there is no portable way, *"I use glibc with x86_64 architecture and there is no plan to run the result elsewhere"*. I check malloc_usable_size().

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: I'm playing the devil's advocate here.  A function that is receiving a pointer can be passed a pointer to a variable, constant or invalid location.  The function, for robustness, cannot guarantee that the pointer came from a `realloc`, `malloc` or `new`.  This assumption is the basis for some hard to debug issues.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well, I can understand you are thinking on the possible most generic way, but I already explained in the question, also only for you in a comment, that *"I know that it points to a memory address previously allocated by the malloc() call."*. Now I explain it third time. May I ask you to not make a fourth time needed again?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, if you want your question to be taken as a non-dupe on account of seeking details of a specific implementation, then it would help to revise the question so that it -- or at this point maybe to ask a new one that -- clearly specifies exactly what you're looking for.  Tagging [glibc] and adding protestations to the question text don't change the fact that both the title and the text of the question seem to be asking for a more generic answer.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica `size_t malloc_usable_size (void *ptr);` seems to fulfill your needs.  Anything else needed that it does not provide?

Comment: Your hook can simply add `sizeof(size_t)` to the allocation request, store the size in the first part of the allocation, and increment the pointer when returning to the caller. Then your `realloc()` and `free()` can subtract from the pointer to get the location of the size.

Comment: Although that might not return a properly aligned result to the caller, so I take it back.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, I tried to edit the question as you suggested.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, I think it qualifies as a possible answer.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, also this is a possible option!

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica:  As I stated before, all you can guarantee, by the standard, is that an address is returned if successful or nullptr if not.  The organization of memory and the exact algorithm for memory allocation is left for the implementation.  For example, the `malloc` function can return an address inside a block set aside for fixed size blocks (this is usually most efficient for small sized allocations like 8-bit up to 32-bits).  You could then have a bit array indicating which blocks are allocated.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, but malloc() does not require an aligned return, as far I know.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, alignment issues do add to the simply solution.  One can prefix a `union` of `size_t` and `max_align_t`

Comment: I still don't see why your hook needs this, though.  You have to have a list somewhere of which allocations were handled by your implementation, and for those you must have recorded the sizes.  When your `realloc` hook is called, if the pointer is in your list, you know its size.  If it's not in your list, then all you can do with it anyway is to either pass it along to glibc's `realloc` if the new size is still small, or if the new size is large, allocate space with your implementation, copy, and pass the original pointer to glibc's `free`.  You don't need to know the old size in either case.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica All `*alloc()` return pointers meeting `max_align_t`. "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental
alignment requirement"

Comment: @NateEldredge Lists are not enough - in a chained list, you can search only linearly. In an arraylist, you can not add-remove at will. Some more complicated structure, for example, a balanced tree is needed - which mostly needs a malloc and I have a circular dependency problem. Furthermore, none of these are thread-safe. Creating a balanced tree entries before all the malloc-ations could work, but it would still not thread-safe.

Comment: @NateEldredge I need a primitive solution - this is a zero-cost project, it is more a home experiment for me, than a job task. The problem is that our VPS provider gave us fast and huge virtualized storage, and nearly zero RAM. I can not enable swap in the VPSes (it is a paravirtualized solution and nearly nothing works). So I implement a "poor man's malloc": malloc() calls create files in /tmp, and mmap() them...

Comment: @NateEldredge Surprisingly, no one did it until now, so I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`malloc_usable_size` returns the number of usable bytes in the block of allocated memory pointed to by the pointer it is passed. This is not necessarily the original requested size; it is the provided size, which may be larger, at the convenience of the allocation software.

The GNU C Library apparently does not document this directly:

- [This part of the GNU C Library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html#Replacing-malloc) says it provides `malloc_usable_size` but does not document its behavior, and it appears to be the only mention in the full documentation there.
- [This GNU C Library page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html) says its API is documented by the [Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), among others, and those pages point to [this for `malloc_usable_size`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html).

So I suppose you may take that last page as having the imprimatur of the GNU C Library. It says `size_t malloc_usable_size(void *ptr)` “returns the number of usable bytes in the block pointed to by `ptr`, a pointer to a block of memory allocated by `malloc(3)` or a related function,” and indicates the function is declared in `<malloc.h>`. Also, if `ptr` is null, zero is returned.

Comment: Don't use this if you're a library. The executable is allowed to swap out `malloc()` by defining it and probably won't have a declaration for `malloc_usable_size`.

Comment: Even if `malloc` has not been replaced, compilers are happy to treat any access past the actual size that was passed to `malloc` as undefined when making transformations, and most `malloc_usable_size` implementations return a somewhat larger value, making the function completely unsafe to use. The only exception I'm aware of is [my implementation in musl libc's mallocng](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc/mallocng/meta.h?id=v1.2.2#n159) which tracks the exact size as part of trapping small overflows.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: What do you mean by "compilers are happy to treat..."?  While there's usually a lot of special knowledge and communication between a C compiler and the standard C library that go beyond what the C language strictly mandates, C compilers have to mostly behave as though the pointer returned by malloc is to an unbound array of memory.  The libc (or the libmalloc if it's separate) can make use of that area (magic values to notice write past end or making sure the end of the alloced area is against a page boundary with an unmapped page to force an invalid memory access).

Comment: @nategoose: What do you think requires a compiler to treat the space returned by `malloc` as unbounded? The specification for `malloc` in C 2018 7.22.3 does not say that, and C implementations are entitled to rely on that in the absence of voluntary adopting other specifications.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If a C program is able to be built using an implementation of malloc other than the one that what the compiler is married to, then that implementation of malloc would have to be in charge what the area around the allocated space is used for.  Additionally the alternative implementation of malloc can be written in C could be compiled using the compiler that is married to its own malloc implementation.  If the compiler itself put hard limits on this then writing a replacement malloc would be severely hindered.

Comment: @nategoose: And that requires, as I said, that the implementation adopt specifications beyond the C standard.

Comment: @nategoose: For example, compile `char *p = malloc(1); memset(p, 42, malloc_usable_size(p));` with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` and the `memset` will trap. This happens because the compiler's `__builtin_object_size` "knows" that the pointed-to object has size 1.